# Barcode not showing up

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

```
<template id="report_label">
            <t t-call="report.html_container">
                <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
                    <div class="page">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="example_class">
                                <t t-esc="o.name" />
                                <t t-esc="o.type" />
                                <p>Size: <span t-esc="o.calculate_size()"/></p>
                                <p>Color: <span t-esc ="o.calculate_color()" /></p>
                                <p>Price: </p>
                                <tr><td colspan="2"><img t-att-src="'/report/barcode/Code128/%s' % 'test-0001'" style="width:100%;height:25px"/>          </td></tr>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </t>
            </t>
        </template>
```

[image]
this is my template and for some reason, barcode is not showing up.

if I test in http://localhost:8069/report/barcode/Code128/test-0001 then it returns me a barcode.

and reportlab is also installed.

same result but smaller borders with

```
<img t-if="o.barcode" t-att-src="'/report/barcode/?type=%s&amp;value=%s&amp;width=%s&amp;height=%s' %('Code128',o.barcode,250,50)"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is Settings > System Parameters need to change

```
Key report.url
Value   http://0.0.0.0:8069
```